# Move a PictureBox with mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, onmousemove

I'm developing an app for windows mobile (Compact Framework 2.0). It has a WinForms with a PictureBox.

I want to move the image of the PictureBox but I don't know how to do it so I choose to move the hole PictureBox.

To do it I use this event:

```
private void imagenMapa_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
      imagenMapa.Left = e.X;
      imagenMapa.Top = e.Y;
      this.Refresh();
}
```

But when I move the PictureBox it blinks and moves every where.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `e.X` and `e.Y` are relative to the picture box (e.g. if the mouse is in the upper left of the picture box, that's 0,0) .

The values for `imagenMapa.Left` and `imagenMapa.Top` are relative to the form (or whatever control contains `imagenMapa`)

If you try to mix values from these two systems without conversion, you're going to get jumps (like you're seeing).

You're probably better off converting the mouse position to the same coordinate system used by the thing that contains the picture box.

You could use [`imagenMapa.PointToScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) to get the mouse coordinates in screen coordinates (or [`Cursor.Position`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx) to get the position directly), and [`yourForm.PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) to get them back in the form coordinates.

Note that depending on your needs, you could accomplish "moving an image within a control" by overriding/handling the [`Paint` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) of a control and drawing the image yourself.  If you did this, you could keep everything in the picturebox coordinates, since those are likely what you would use when you called [`graphicsObject.DrawImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage.aspx).

Comment: daniel this is nice theory but can you put it into code please? i have the same exact question but in VB.net. please help!

Answer (score 7):

Actual Code (Requires .NET Framework 3.5 and beyond, not sure if this is available in the Compact Framework)...

```
// Global Variables
private int _xPos;
private int _yPos;
private bool _dragging;

// Register mouse events
pictureBox.MouseUp += (sender, args) =>
{
    var c = sender as PictureBox;
    if (null == c) return;
    _dragging = false;
};

pictureBox.MouseDown += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (args.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
    _dragging = true;
    _xPos = args.X;
    _yPos = args.Y;
};

pictureBox.MouseMove += (sender, args) =>
{
    var c = sender as PictureBox;
    if (!_dragging || null == c) return;
    c.Top = args.Y + c.Top - _yPos;
    c.Left = args.X + c.Left - _xPos;
};
```

Comment: This works flawlessly! Thank you for taking the time to share code :)

Answer (score 1):

e.X & e.Y is in the coordinate space of the pictureBox, imagenMapa.Left & imagenMapa.Top is in the coordinate space of the Form. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Also don't forget to set your form to double buffered, that might help with the flickering, but for the actual positioning of it, I like Daniel L's suggestion

Comment: I'm using Compact Framework and Forms doesn't have double buffer. How can I do this?

Comment: This link describes how to create a "double buffered" Picture box.  I'm sorry I guess I wasn't paying attn. when you said CF 2.0 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574958/c-cf-winforms-and-double-buffer

Answer (score 1):

Embrace math!

```
control.Left = control.Left - (_lastMousePos.X - currentMousePos.X);
control.Top = control.Top - (_lastMousePos.Y - currentMousePos.Y);
```

Quick explanation:
You get the difference from the mouse positions and apply it to the object you want to move.

Example:
If the old mouse X position is 382, and the new one is 385, then the difference is -3. If the controls current X position is 10 then 10 - (-3) = 13

Why: 
It works for anything, and is much cheaper than constantly converting coordinates back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you have done is correct. But you gave the MouseMove property to the picturebox. You should give that property to the Form(background).

ex:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  imagenMapa.Left = e.X;
  imagenMapa.Top = e.Y;
}
```