# c# CF, WinForms and double buffer

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, doublebuffered

I have a CF 2.0 app with a PictureBox on a Form. I want to move the PictureBox with mouse move and I need to add Double Buffer to the form to avoid flickering.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the Form double-buffered, you need the PB to be.  That's not so easy to come by in CF.  However, you could create your own control, PB is pretty simple.  For example:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyPictureBox : Control {
  private Image mImage;
  public Image Image {
    get { return mImage; }
    set { mImage = value; Invalidate(); }
  }
  protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent) {
    // Do nothing
  }
  protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.ClientSize.Width, this.ClientSize.Height)) {
      using (Graphics bgr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
        bgr.Clear(this.BackColor);
        if (mImage != null) bgr.DrawImage(mImage, 0, 0);
      }
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
  }
}
```

Hopefully, I didn't use stuff that isn't available in CF...

Comment: PB? What is the meaning of PB?

Comment: It doesn't work. I need double buffer on Form because I moving the entire PictureBox (I think).

Comment: This is the correct code, but what you'll need to do is create a container (a panel for example) that draws like this. Worst case scenario is that you'll have to swap out a picture box for something custom you manually draw and control inside the panel.

Comment: Also works like a charm when drawing complex things that take time. I Preallocate the bitmap, resize it when needed (on Form.ResizeEnd), draw the stuff (splines with 1000s of points) into the bitmap and draw the bitmap into the PB.